# calculating (length*qty = total(m), total(m)*price = total price) but the total price wont show results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculating multiplication on my dynamic table (length*qty = total(m), total(m)*price = total price) but the total price wont show results.

sorry my bad english

```js
 $('#tab_logic tbody tr').each(function(i, element) {
  var html = $(this).html();
  if(html!==''){
      var qty2 = $(this).find('.qty2').val();
     var length = $(this).find('.length').val();
       var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val(length*qty2);
     var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
     $(this).find('.total').val(qty*price);
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center"> # </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Product </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Width </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Length </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Qty </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Total(m) </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Price Rate </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Total Price </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id='addr0'>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name='product[]'  placeholder='Enter Product Name' class="form-control"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='width[]'  placeholder='Enter Product Name' class="form-control"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='length[]'  placeholder='Enter Product Name' class="form-control length"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='qty2[]'  placeholder='Enter Product Name' class="form-control qty2"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='qty[]' placeholder='Enter Qty' class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='Enter Unit Price' class="form-control price" step="0.00" min="0"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control total" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: You should place all relevant code needed to reproduce your problem in a snippet here instead of an image. Click edit then click on the document icon with <> inside it.

Comment: Imagine someone came to you asking for help with code.  And they gave you a picture of the code.  How annoyed would you feel having to look at the picture, transcribe the code in the picture to text, before you could even potentially get started helping them.  Wouldn't it be much nicer to the people you are asking help from, if you offered them the actual code instead?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Comment: sorry i already edit it

Comment: @IndoBatch What is `#tab_logic` supposed to be? Its not in your html code at all

Comment: See this quite a few times on SO - `.val(newvalue)` chains the *element*, it doesn't return the newvalue, eg `$("#id").val(123).show();`  so `qty=$("#id").val(123)` -> qty = the jquery object, not the newvalue, `qty*price` makes no sense.   Apply some basic debugging: add some console.log (eg `console.log(qty2,length,qty,price)` and/or step through and actually look at what's being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell from your code snippets, you want to populate the total fields. I made a minimal reproducible example based off of your code. I added `id` attributes to the `input` tags and I added a calculate button which does the math to calculate the totals for the fields. Hopefully this can get you on the correct path for you to just take what I have here and apply it to your code.

```js
$(document).on('click','#calc', function(){
 var qty2 = $('#qty2').val();
  var length = $('#length').val();
  var temp = qty2 * length;
  var qty = $('#qty').val(temp).val();
  var price = $('#price').val();
  $('#totalNum').val(qty*price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id ='tab_logic'>
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center"> # </th>
        <th class="text-center"> Product </th>
        <th class="text-center"> Width </th>
        <th class="text-center"> Length </th>
        <th class="text-center"> Qty </th>
        <th class="text-center"> Total(m) </th>
        <th class="text-center"> Price Rate </th>
        <th class="text-center"> Total Price </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id='addr0'>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name='product[]'  placeholder='Enter Product Name' class="form-control"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='width[]'  placeholder='Enter Product Name' class="form-control"/></td>
        <td><input id="length" type="number" name='length[]'  placeholder='Enter Product Name' class="form-control"/></td>
        <td><input id="qty2" type="number" name='qty2[]'  placeholder='Enter Product Name' class="form-control"/></td>
        <td><input id ="qty" type="number" name='qty[]' placeholder='Enter Qty' class="form-control" step="0" min="0"/></td>
        <td><input id="price" type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='Enter Unit Price' class="form-control" step="0.00" min="0"/></td>
        <td><input id="totalNum" type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control total" readonly/></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      <button id="calc">Calculate</button>
```